# Why is not the definition of probability distribution consistent with the definition of Binomial Distributions?

Tags: probability, distributions, binomial-distribution, terminology

Definition of Probability Distribution:

> A probability distribution is a table or an equation that links each
>   outcome of a statistical experiment with its probability of
>   occurrence.

And,

Definition of Binomial Probability Distribution:

> A binomial distribution is a specific probability distribution which
>   is used to model the probability of obtaining one of two outcomes, a
>   certain number of times (k), out of fixed number of trials (N) of a
>   discrete random event.

Are there two definitions consistent with each other? I think no.

Why? Because, how is a Binomial Distribution acting like **a table or equation that links each out come of the experiment with its probability of occurrence**?

Comment: they are perfectly consistent. the [binomial probability distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) gives you the probability of the number of successes in a set of _n_ independent yes/no experiments, each one having identical probability of success _p_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define what's an *outcome*. So, in case of Binomial distribution the outcome is "event occurred k times out of n trials". So you have a table with n+1 rows from 0 to n, each one representing one outcome, i.e. k occurrences of event. Each row will have a corresponding probability. Hence, the table of outcomes.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine an experiment where you toss a coin $N$ times and count the number of heads that occurred. Imagine that the coin doesn't necessarily have to be fair and it can return heads with some probability $p$. Binomial distribution is a *function* parameterized by $p$ and $N$ that maps the number of heads that occurred, $k$, with probabilities. In here $p$ and $N$ are features of the experiment and $k$ is the outcome. So yes, it's consistent with the definition provided.